# CodeMirror doesn't scroll down completely, Cursor is hidden behind div

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

I would like to use the very excellent texteditor **CodeMirror** in fullscreen mode in a browser window and I would like to add a fixed header for some kind of menu - or at least space for a few buttons with some functionality.

So I've added a div with "position: fixed" to the top and added a padding-top to the div with the codemirror object. The **problem** comes up, when there's enough text that scrolling happens. After moving the cursor down/scrolling the content up and moving the cursor up again, the cursor goes behind the div but the content doesn't scroll fully down. Cursor is hidden, I cannot see the content. Only scrolling via scrollbar works.

Do I need to change the html/css with the fixed div? 
Or do I need to check whether the cursor comes behind/under the div and I have to let CodeMirror scroll manually? I tried this but didn't manage to do it programmatically :-(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/doc/docs.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src=http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js></script>
    <script src=http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js></script>
    <style type=text/css>
        .CodeMirror {float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>  
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position: fixed; height: 28px; z-index:999; width: 100%; background: lightgray;">
    <button>Some action</button>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top: 23px">
    <textarea id=content name="content"></textarea>
  </div>
    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('content'), {
        mode: 'application/x-httpd-php',
        lineNumbers: true
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

check out here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/fxvef3bw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on my own.

Instead of two overlapping divs, I use two divs (non-overlapping), with style "**position: absolute**". They don't overlap, so scrolling is fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/doc/docs.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src=http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js></script>
    <script src=http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js></script>
    <style type=text/css>
        .CodeMirror {float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>  
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 1px; position: absolute; margin: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: auto; height: 24px; background: lightgrey;">
        <button>some action</button>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 1px; position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 28px; bottom: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; ">
        <textarea id="content" name="content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('content'), {
        mode: 'application/x-httpd-php',
        lineNumbers: true
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Updated jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fxvef3bw/2/

I hope I can get some comments about possible side effects or drawbacks of the position absolute. Otherwise it seems to be fine for me.